# Error check detect mobile browser when key in domain have "www"

Tags: php, detect

I have a sample code:

```
<?php
$mobileDetect = $this->mobileDetect(); //Retrieve "\Mobile_Detect" object
if($mobileDetect->isMobile()) {
    $mobile_url = "http://m." . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: " . $mobile_url);
}
?>
```

When I key in `domain.com` on mobile browser, result true with redirect sub domain `m.domain.com`.

But when I key in `www.domain.com` is result wrong with redirect sub domain `m.www.domain.com` => how to fix it?

Comment: Try `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` or `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']` with `parse_url()` insteat of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Comment: $domaimn = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$mobileDetect = $this->mobileDetect(); //Retrieve "\Mobile_Detect" object
if($mobileDetect->isMobile()) {
    $mobile_url = "http://m." . str_replace('www.','',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ). $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: " . $mobile_url);
}
?>
```